# Kotlin reflection on object instance

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I've been trying some stuff from `kotlin.reflection` during my project, and got stuck on something what occurs to me as hard to understand, I have declared object as follows:

```
object WebsiteMapping
{
    const val ADMIN = "/admin"
}
```

once I call:

```
Arrays
  .stream(WebsiteMapping::class.java.declaredFields)
  .forEach { field -> println(field.type) }
```

what I get is:

```
class java.lang.String
class mapping.WebsiteMapping
```

When I looked a little bit into what is behind declaredFields invocation I grasped why it works as it is, but is there any convenient way of taking only declared consts within that object without getting also root of the whole structure?

Answer (score 4):

The field with the type `class mapping.WebsiteMapping` is, basically, not the root of the structure but a special field generated in the object type that holds the reference to the singleton object.

In Kotlin, this field is named `INSTANCE` by convention. You can therefore filter the fields that you get from the class as follows:

```
WebsiteMapping::class.java.declaredFields
    .filter { it.name != "INSTANCE" }
    .forEach { println(it.type) }
```

Another solution is to switch from `java.reflect.*` to the Kotlin reflection API `kotlin.reflect` (needs a dependency on the [`kotlin-reflect` module](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect)), which automatically filters the property:

```
WebsiteMapping::class.memberProperties
    .forEach { println(it.returnType) }
```